# Pytest argument from command line with fixture

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

**Code** :  `Test1.py`

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def tc_setup(start):
    if start == "20d":
        print('20d is sent')
    else:
        print('not in list')

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--start')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def start(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--start')
```

**From Command Line**

```
pytest -v test1.py --start=20d
```

Also tried,

```
pytest -v test1.py --start 20d
```

**Error Message**

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --start=20d
  inifile: None
```

How can I send parameters from command line and `pytest`.
I'm running this from bash shell on linux ubuntu terminal.

**Version**

```
pytest 7.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it worked for me. Created two files : `conftest.py` and    `myso_test.py`. You basically need to have a conftest file

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--start")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def start(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--start")
```

**myso_test.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def tc_setup(start):
    if start == "20d":
        print('20d is sent')
    else:
        print('not in list')

def test_var():
    assert True
```

Running the command:

```
pytest myso_test.py -s -v --start="20d"
```

Output:

```
myso_test.py::test_var 20d is sent
PASSED
```

Running the command:

```
pytest myso_test.py -s -v --start="20dw"
```

Output:

```
myso_test.py::test_var not in list
PASSED
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can move the fixture `tc_setup` into the `conftest.py` file.